# Why does it say my code for Sim City was already used?

Tags: simcity-2013

I bought it completely out of the store using my own money nobody but me and my Dad so nobody could steal the code. I tried entering the code when I got home but it failed to work. It said This code has already been used. I never used it or anyone did and that was a complete waste of money if it is not gonna work. Does anyone have a solution to this or a reason why it did this cause I am not just gonna buy something with my money and have it go to waste.

Comment: My advice?  Contact EA's Tech Support.

Comment: Which store? Have you contacted them? Was the game definitely unopened when you bought it?

Comment: Contacting EA tech support and/or the store you purchased the game from are your best options.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this, you have 2 options.

1. Contact the support of either the developer or publisher of the game. In this case [Electronic Arts](http://help.ea.com/en/contact-us/new/?product=simcity). Explain your situation and be prepared to provide some evidence to back your claims. A receit of purchase and the physical copy of the code slip should suffice.
2. Contact the store you bought the game from. Tell them that you want a replacement or a refund and also tell them why. ("Game does not work because the code in it has already be used. Most likely illigaly.")

Doing option 1 before option 2 is your best bet. You'll most likely either get your code working or get a replacement. And if you don't, you have a better case for asking a refund, as you couldn't get the game working even *after* contacting the support.